# How to change the physical properties of the robot and plane to apply Domain Randomization ?- Drake

Tags: drake

I’m working with a quadruped robot to learn locomotion behavior with DRL using Ros2 and Drake in c++, and I want to apply domain randomization in my learning.

I would like some advice from the community to How I can change the physical properties of the robot (like mass, inertia, joint friction) and plane properties dynamically during the training.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is that you can set the parameter in the context for each simulation. Here is a quick code for doing that

```py
plant = MultibodyPlant(...)
simulator = Simulator(plant)
plant.GetBodyByName("my_body").SetMass(simulator.get_mutable_context(), new_mass)
simulator.AdvanceTo(T)
```

Notice calling `SetMass` function, which takes the context as an input. You can call `SetSpatialInertiaInBodyFrame` and `SetDamping` methods, both take `context` as an input.